# cannot resolve constructor anonymous MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am using [BottomSheet library](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet) setting this method giving me

> cannot resolve constructor anonymous MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'MenuSheetView(MyProjectName.....FragmentClassName, com.flipboard.bottomsheet.commons.MenuSheetView.MenuType, java.lang.String, anonymous android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener)'
```

I am doing it as the same as [this library sample](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet/blob/master/bottomsheet-sample/src/main/java/com/flipboard/bottomsheet/sample/MenuActivity.java)

```
private void TestBS(){
    bottomSheet.showWithSheetView(
            new MenuSheetView(ViewLesson.this, MenuSheetView.MenuType.LIST, "Create...", 
            new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    return true;
                }
            }));
}
```

Will anyone know from what the error is produced

It just display the error message I have posted
[image]

[MenuSheetView](https://codeshare.io/ar9vyY)

ViewLesson

```
public class ViewLesson extends Fragment {

private Button CreateBtn;
private TextView DescriptionTV,Header;
private BottomSheetLayout bottomSheet;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    fetchData();

    return rootview;
}

private void fetchData() {....}

private void TestBS(){
    bottomSheet.showWithSheetView(
            new MenuSheetView(getContext(), MenuSheetView.MenuType.LIST, "Create...", new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Log.i("dddd","ss");
                    //Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (bottomSheet.isSheetShowing()) {
                        bottomSheet.dismissSheet();
                    }
                            /*if (item.getItemId() == R.id.reopen) {
                                showMenuSheet(menuType == MenuSheetView.MenuType.LIST ? MenuSheetView.MenuType.GRID : MenuSheetView.MenuType.LIST);
                            }*/
                    return true;
                }
            }));
}
```

}

`getActivity()` or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` is not working also

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'MenuSheetView(android.content.Context, com.flipboard.bottomsheet.commons.MenuSheetView.MenuType, java.lang.String, anonymous android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener)'
```

Any suggestions, any solutions?

Comment: you have an error in your costructor. if you stands on your error line you can see a comparison between what is expected and what you are passing

Comment: @firegloves It just display the error message i posted see my edit

Comment: post MenuSheetView code if you need more help

Comment: here it is  ( the library sample) https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet/blob/master/bottomsheet-sample/src/main/java/com/flipboard/bottomsheet/sample/MenuActivity.java

Comment: I can't find MenuSheetView code, please post here

Comment: sorry about that I didn't see the name well here it is, https://codeshare.io/ar9vyY

Comment: ViewLesson is a context?

Comment: ViewLesson is a Fragment at which I want to display the Sheet, event getContext gives can not reslove const

Comment: ViewLesson.this.getActivity() ?

Comment: that is the only param not matching with constructos, this should be the error

Comment: I have added ViewLesson also, event getContext in the fragment won't work ?!

Comment: Fragment's use `getActivity()` to get a `Context`

Comment: @cricket_007 getActivity() or getActivity().getApplicationContext() is not working here, `Cannot resolve constructor 'MenuSheetView(android.content.Context,....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener` to
`new`**MenuSheetView**`.OnMenuItemClickListener` solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using an undefined constructor. that means that your code does not match any known constructor of `MenuSheetView` class.

According to your first error it seems that ViewLesson.this refers to a fragment, that doesn't extend `Context` class